# Django generic relations modelling

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to model something in Django and it doesn't seem quite right. A `Book` and a `Movie` can have one or more `Person`s involved in it, each of whom has a `Role` (like "Author" or "Director") on that `Book` or `Movie`.

I'm doing this with [Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) something like this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = GenericRelation('Role', related_query_name='books')

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = GenericRelation('Role', related_query_name='movies')
```

Which seems to work, but it seems odd when getting all the `Book`s a `Person` has worked on:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)

for role in person.role_set.all():
    print(role.role_name)
    for book in role.books.all():
        print(book.title)
```

The `for book in role.books.all()` feels wrong - like a role can have multiple books. I think I want a more direct relationship between a person working on a particular book/movie.

Is there a better way to model this?

Comment: Have you considered using a many to many relationship through a model? E.g. your book/movie models would have a many to many relationship through the role? See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#s-extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I think the problem with that would be using the role for multiple models - Books, Music, and other things - rather than just one. Which is why I went for Generic relations. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ahh... I think I can just do `print(role.role_name, role.content_object.title)`... the `content_object` is the book or movie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was me, I'd try an approach as follows using the many to many relationship through the role model. (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#s-extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

As you mentioned above in the comments, the trouble comes because you have several models (book and movie) that would require this relationship. The solution to this, is to use a BaseRole model and create separate models for movie roles and book roles. Something like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class BaseRole(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MovieRole(BaseRole):
    movie = models.ForeignKey('Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class BookRole(BaseRole):
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='BookRole')


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='MovieRole')
```

That way when you'd like to filter on all the Books a Person has worked on, you can do that as follows:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
books = Book.objects.filter(roles=person).distinct()
```

The `distinct()` call is necessary, as a person could have more than one role on a book/movie (e.g. they could be a producer and the director), so without it, the filter would return the an instance of the book for each role that the person had in the movie/book.

### UPDATE

In response to you comment, perhaps a better solution would be to use Django Polymorphic (https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).

So you'd set your models up something like this:

```
from django.db import models

from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    media = models.ForeignKey('Media', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Media(PolymorphicModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Role')


class Book(Media):
    pass

class Movie(Media):
    pass
```

That way you can still get all the books a person has worked on by:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
books = Book.objects.filter(roles=person).distinct()
```

But you can also get all of the media that a person has worked on by:

```
media = person.media_set.all()
```

And yes you're right, there is no point in having the content_type and object_id, so I've removed these fields.

Comment: Thanks for this! This way is simpler in many respects. I think the only downside is that you can't get a single list of all the things the person has worked on (`person.role_set.all()` using GenericRelations) without manually combining several QuerySets. BTW, doing it this way is there any point having `content_type` and `object_id` in `BaseRole`?

Comment: @PhilGyford, I've update the answer to address your points. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Thanks again! I have plenty of choices now - just need to decide what I actually need to do :)

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Django's generic relations may not be the best choice for this case.
Instead, it looks like some form of inheritance is more appropriate.

### why not generic relations?

Django works with relational databases. Much of the power, efficiency, and reliability of a relational database originates from the fact that the relations between tables are fixed by the *designer* (or developer, or whatever): Just by looking at the model definitions, you know how the tables are related. The *user* cannot influence this.

A `GenericForeignKey`, on the other hand, *breaks this basic concept*, by allowing the *user* to create new relations to *any* other table in the database. These relations exist only in the *data*, not in the *schema*. The *designer* cannot know which relations will exist at any point in time, nor can the model definitions tell us how the tables are related. For that, we need to look at the actual data from the database. Needless to say this [clever trick](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD340.html) complicates matters greatly, and makes relational integrity difficult, if not impossible, to maintain.

Still, there are some use-cases where the flexibility of `GenericForeignKey` is exactly what is needed. Django's own example of a [TaggedItem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) illustrates this well.

However, the OP's case is *not* one of them, as far as I can see.

### what then?

The [answer by @tdsymonds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527721) points in the right direction, which is, to use some form of inheritance from a `Media` class. However, I believe using `django-polymorphic` overcomplicates the matter, as there are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896834) of implementing this using plain Django.

Probably the simplest method, although maybe not the most query-efficient one, is to use Django's [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) (a.k.a. [class-table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)).

Applied to the OP's example, this becomes:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(to='Media', through='Role')

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    media = models.ForeignKey('Media', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Media(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(Media):
    pass

class Movie(Media):
    pass
```

Note that `Role` has a `ForeignKey` directly to `Media`, which can be set using either a `Media` object, a `Book` object, a `Movie` object, or any other subclass you decide to add. The subclasses can have additional attributes. We can easily get a list of all roles a `Person` played, regardless of the type of `Media`, via `person.roles.all()` (a basic [many-to-many relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)).

To view the roles in the admin, add an inline, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mediaroles.models import Person, Role, Book, Movie, Media

class RoleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Role
    extra = 0

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (RoleInline,)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
admin.site.register([Role, Book, Movie])
```

Comment: Thanks for your well-explained thoughts on this. It's nice to have more options.